# Calculating free NAS space percentage

Tags: powershell, nas

I've got a NAS in my network whose used/free data I can receive by

```
Get-PSDrive w | Select-Object used,free
```

What I want is, if the NAS reached 70% of its overall disk space, another script (which I already own) should get executed. The script does not have to run permanently, one disk space check a day via Task Scheduler would be okay.

How can I calculate the 70% overall disk space and what do I need to execute the other script after the check was successful?

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the percentage from the values of the `Used` and `Free` properties:

```
used / (used + free)
```

Check if the result is greater than 70% (0.7) and run the other script if it is. You don't actually need to select the properties first. Simply filter the output of `Get-PSDrive` with a `Where-Object` statement.

```
Get-PSDrive w |
  Where-Object { $_.Used / ($_.Used + $_.Free) -gt 0.7 } |
  ForEach-Object { & 'C:\path\to\other.ps1' }
```